# How to make clickable Header in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to make my Header clickable to navigate to homepage but the code below is not working, I'm sure that there should be a really easy way to do it.

```
const Header = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="font-weight-light display-1 text-center" onClick={navigate('/')}>
        The X app
      </h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React executes `navigate('/')` on every render (and assigns the *results* to the onClick prop)

Shouldn't this be `onClick={() => navigate('/')}` ?